# How to hide/show title when content null

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

My code is to build a menu ( they are divide into some groups) and if 1 group without any item showed, the title of group is no need to show.

How to hide the ListItem when following MenuList null?
    Thank you

This is my code:

```
<ListItem className="group-menu-title"> "Basic"  </ListItem>
<MenuList
           children={item.data.map(
           (link) => {
           var resource = getResourceByLink(link, resources);
           if (resource != null) {
               resource.icon = typeof (resource.icon) === 'undefined' ? DefaultIcon : resource.icon;
               var icon = createElement(resource.icon)
               var label = resource.options.label ? resource.options.label : resource.name
               return <WithPermissions
                        render={({ permissions }) => (
                         isShow(permissions) ?
                               <MenuItemLink
                                     className={classes.menuItem}
                                     to={link}                                                           
                                      primaryText={label}
                                     leftIcon={icon}
                                      onClick={onMenuClick} />
                                : null
                         )}
                     />
              }
              })}>
     </MenuList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to check if a certain value exists and then render the component.

e.g. Since you're mapping `item.data` we'll use that as the condition to check for.

```
{item.data.length > 0 && ( 
  <ListItem className="group-menu-title">
    "Basic"
  </ListItem> 
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this, use a **ternary operator** check and construct a const `ListItem`.

```
const ListItem = item.data.length > 0 ? <ListItem className="group-menu-title"> "Basic"  </ListItem> : null;
```

then bind it like `{ListItem}`, also this is going to look neat.

```
{ListItem} // this is gonna be null if there is no data//
<MenuList
           children={item.data.map(
           (link) => {
           var resource = getResourceByLink(link, resources);
           if (resource != null) {
               resource.icon = typeof (resource.icon) === 'undefined' ? DefaultIcon : resource.icon;
               var icon = createElement(resource.icon)
               var label = resource.options.label ? resource.options.label : resource.name
               return <WithPermissions
                        render={({ permissions }) => (
                         isShow(permissions) ?
                               <MenuItemLink
                                     className={classes.menuItem}
                                     to={link}                                                           
                                      primaryText={label}
                                     leftIcon={icon}
                                      onClick={onMenuClick} />
                                : null
                         )}
                     />
              }
              })}>
     </MenuList>
```